# Error in SQL syntax;check the manual that corredponds to your MySQL server

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to insert a record to a mysql database using c# but  I always saw this error message:

> You have error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corredponds to
>   your MySQL        server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'Order(idOrder, Quantity, Date,          Menu_idMenu)VALUES(10002,
>   '1', '3/17/2013 12:00' at line 1

this is the code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
     {
           com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Order (idOrder, Quantity, Date, Menu_idMenu) VALUES (" + 10002 + ", '" +row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "', '"+DateTime.Today.ToString()+"', '" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "')";
           int insert = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

what does it mean?

Comment: _Well_, none of this answers didn't helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You have reserved keywords in your query, `Order`. Quote it and be happy.

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `Order` (idOrder, Quantity, Date, Menu_idMenu) VALUES (" + 10002 + ", '" +row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "', '"+DateTime.Today.ToString()+"', '" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "')";
```

Also, it is good practice to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` and `Order` are *[reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)* on MySQL.

Use them between `''`

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `Order` (idOrder, Quantity, Date, Menu_idMenu) VALUES (" + 10002 + ", '" +row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "', '"+DateTime.Today.ToString()+"', '" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "')";
```

And **always** use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of codes open for an *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

Actually, you can use `Date` without quotes.

> MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because
>   many people previously used them.

Since, I suggest you using *parameterized queries*, here how you can use it with your code;

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `Order` (idOrder, Quantity, Date, Menu_idMenu) VALUES (@idOrder, @Quantity, @Date, @Menu_idMenu)";

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idOrder", "10002");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Today.ToString());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Menu_idMenu", row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```